# plusSeconds in ZonedDateTime not working as expected

Tags: java, utc, dst, pst, zoneddatetime

Below is the logic we are trying to code.

We have startdate(SD) and enddate(ED) in UTC, we first convert startdate to PST(SD_PST) and then add difference between startdate and enddate to the PST converted startdate (SD_PST+(ED minus SD)) to obtain ED_PST(end date in PST)

Below is our partial code.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(sud.getStartTime().toInstant(),
sud.getEndTime().toInstant()); // Sun Mar 12 08:00:00 PDT 2017 - [sud.getStartTime()] & Sun Mar 12 09:00:00 PDT 2017 - [sud.getEndTime()] 

ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(convertToPst(sud.getStartTime()).toInstant(),
        ZoneId.systemDefault()); // ldt now is 2017-03-12T1:00-08:00[PST8PDT]

ldt = ldt.plusSeconds(duration.getSeconds()); // ldt now is 2017-03-12T3:00-07:00[PST8PDT] , duration.getSeconds() is 3600
Date f2 = Date.from(ldt.toInstant()); // output Sun Mar 12 03:00:00 PDT 2017
```

I get it that daylight saving is affecting the output, but I am unable to understand how 1 hour extra is added, my expected output is  `2017-03-12T2:00-07:00[PST8PDT]` (I understand that in dst -7 hours gets added).

Please help me understand the output.

Comment: So we are running the code in jvm running in PST timezone(Denver, CO, USA), startdate and enddate are fetched from DB using hibernate. Basically adding one hour to 2017-03-12T1:00-08:00[PST8PDT] makes it to 2017-03-12T3:00-07:00[PST8PDT]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Why wouldn't you just add seconds to the UTC time (the `Instant`)?

Comment: Also, I highly recommend you set your system / JVM time zone to `America/Los_Angeles` or `America/Vancouver` instead of `PST8PDT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told in the comments that **adding one hour to `2017-03-12T1:00-08:00[PST8PDT]` makes it to `2017-03-12T3:00-07:00[PST8PDT]`**. Well, this is correct.

This happens because Dayligh Saving Time (DST, or summer time) in `PST8PDT` timezone [starts at the second Sunday of March, at 2 AM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone#Daylight_time). When the time reaches 2 AM, the clocks shift 1 hour forward to 3 AM and the offset changes from `-08:00` to `-07:00`.

Take this code:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-03-12T01:00-08:00[PST8PDT]");
System.out.println(zdt); // 2017-03-12T01:00-08:00[PST8PDT]
System.out.println(zdt.plusHours(1)); // 2017-03-12T03:00-07:00[PST8PDT]
```

The output is:

> 2017-03-12T01:00-08:00[PST8PDT]
>   2017-03-12T03:00-07:00[PST8PDT]

Note that at 1 AM the offset was `-08:00`. Then I added 1 hour, and the local time should have changed to 2 AM. But at 2 AM, DST starts and the clock is shifted 1 hour **forward** to 3 AM, and the offset changes to `-07:00`.

This can become more clear if you get the corresponding `Instant` of each date (so you'll have those same dates in UTC):

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-03-12T01:00-08:00[PST8PDT]");
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant()); // 2017-03-12T09:00:00Z
System.out.println(zdt.plusHours(1).toInstant()); // 2017-03-12T10:00:00Z
```

The output is:

> 2017-03-12T09:00:00Z
>   2017-03-12T10:00:00Z

Note that the difference is really 1 hour.